# RxJava how to filter sub tree and then return the tree

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

If I have an `Observable<JsonOrderList>`.

`JsonOrderList` defined below :

```
public class JsonOrderList {

  public List<Order> data;
  public int currentCount;
  public int currentPage;
  public int pageCount;

}
```

API defined below :

`Observable<JsonOrderList> orderApi.orderList(before, after, limit, state)`

I want to filter/process `List<Order> data` and then return `JsonOrderList`

```
orderApi.orderList(before, after, limit, state){
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
//How to process List<Order> data

.subscribe(new Action1<JsonOrderList>() {
    @Override
    public void call(JsonOrderList rpOrderList) {
        pushSuccessData(ID_GET_ORDER_LIST, rpOrderList);
    }
}, new Action1<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
        pushErrorData(ID_GET_ORDER_LIST, throwable);
    }
}));
```

EDIT:

```
doOnNext(new Action1<JsonOrderList>() {
        @Override
        public void call(JsonOrderList jsonOrderList) {
            //can i use rxjava operator replace loop
            for(Order order : jsonOrderList.data){
                order.setBuyer(goodsApi.getBuyer(order.getBuyerId));
            }
        }
})
```

goodsApi.getBuyer(id) request server to get BuyerInfo

> Could I use rxjava operator replace loop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map` operator:

```
orderApi.orderList(before, after, limit, state)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map(new Func1<List<Order>, JsonOrderList>() {
            @Override
            public JsonOrderList call(List<Order> orders) {
                JsonOrderList jsonOrderList = new JsonOrderList();
                // ... do some stuff to fill jsonOrderList
                return jsonOrderList;
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Action1<JsonOrderList>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JsonOrderList rpOrderList) {
                pushSuccessData(ID_GET_ORDER_LIST, rpOrderList);
            }
        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                pushErrorData(ID_GET_ORDER_LIST, throwable);
            }
        });
```

EDIT:

After further explanation of the problem, I suggest you use the following code.

I would advice you NOT to use `.filter(...)` operator as it will change your stream (you would get a different object in `subscribe`).

```
orderApi.orderList(before, after, limit, state)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(new Action1<JsonOrderList>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JsonOrderList jsonOrderList) {
                //do something with jsonOrderList.data
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Action1<JsonOrderList>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JsonOrderList rpOrderList) {
                pushSuccessData(ID_GET_ORDER_LIST, rpOrderList);
            }
        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                pushErrorData(ID_GET_ORDER_LIST, throwable);
            }
        });
```

Comment: We cannot `new JsonOrderList`, because JsonOrderList is from json of server return .  orderApi.orderList is return Observable<JsonOrderList> not Observable<List<Order>>.  Thank you all the same！！！

Comment: @Chiclaim, sorry I misunderstood your "How to process List<Order> data" comment. So you want to process your `JsonOrderList` to get your `List<Order>`, right? you want me to edit the answer or is the current version enough for you to point you in the right direction?

Comment: `@Bartek Lipinski`  I want process `List<Order>` of  `JsonOrderList ` , when I subscribe, I want to get  `JsonOrderList ` .

Comment: @Chiclaim ok, I think I get it. Check my edit to my answer

Comment: `@Bartek Lipinski` Thank you so much!  you know JsonOrderList contain List<Order>, Order has a field `buyerId` . I want to get `Buer info` from server by `buyerId`. Can I only get `Buer info` by loop in `doOnNext`. ``` foreach(Order order : list) getBuyer(order)

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to accept it :) !

Comment: `@Bartek Lipinski` Please see my EDIT.

Comment: @Chiclaim if you need more help, post a new question. I consider this one - answered.

Comment: Thank you for your answers , I accepted you answer!